# resize textarea с добавлением скролла родителю

Tags: html, css

Есть форма связи - модальное окно, в которой находится textareа. Нужно чтобы при resiz'e можно было растянуть textarea на высоту большую чем у контейнера, а у самого контейнера появилась прокрутка.

```css
form {
    width: 540px;
    max-height: 700px;
    max-width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    z-index: 1900;
    background-color: gray;
    padding: 25px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

textarea {
  resize:vertical;
}
```

```html
<form action="">
  <input type="text">
  <textarea></textarea>
  <input type="text">
</form>
```

В данном примере, можно растянуть поле ввода на всю высоту, но не больше. Если подозрения, что это из-за `display: flex`. Просвятите пожалуйста

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё верно - `flex` тут лишний:

```css
form {
  width: 540px;
  max-height: 700px;
  max-width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  z-index: 1900;
  background-color: gray;
  padding: 25px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

form * {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

textarea {
  resize: vertical;
  height: calc(100% - 50px);
}
```

```html
<form action="">
  <input type="text">
  <textarea></textarea>
  <input type="text">
</form>
```

Comment: Я сам примерно к этому решению и пришел, только мне бы хотелось понять как работает flexbox в этой ситуации. Тоесть если расположить блоки в колонку через `display:flexbox` и `flex-direction:column`, почему textarea не растягивается больше высоты родителя?

Comment: @Dantessss не растягивается потому, что упирается в нижний `input`, а он в свою очередь ограничен `flex`-ом. Все элементы во `flex` расположены как бы в одной плоскости, поэтому с ним не "прокатывают" всякие `absolute` и `overflow`. Как-то так.

Comment: окей, примерно понял, а можно где нить поподробней узнать об этом? А то я в гугле ничего не нашел на эту тему